# discord.py AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'client' on the latest pip version

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

when I use this ^ code I get the error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "c:\Users\zist\Discord Bot\main.py", line 46, in <module> 
@bot.client AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'client'
```

This is how I define `bot`:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)
bot = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

With older versions of `pip` I get

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'app_commands' from 'discord' (C:\Users\zist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord__init__.py)
```

I tried looking up for the solution that didn't give me an error and I haven't come across any.

Comment: Can you provide a full traceback, please?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\zist\Discord Bot\main.py", line 46, in <module>
    @bot.client
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'client'

Comment: Where is `bot` defined?

Comment: intents = discord.Intents.default() 1 
intents.message_content = True 2 
client = discord.Client(intents=intents) 3

tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client) 4 
bot = discord.Client(intents=intents) 5

Comment: Why do you think `bot` has a `client` attribute? You seem to have used a `@bot.client` decorator somewhere in code you haven't included. Perhaps you meant `@bot.command`?

Comment: thats how I learned to define bot